# Running balance calculation using window functions with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a way to calculate the running balance of an account.
Below is my schema and the query I tried.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
   id   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,date DATE  NOT NULL
  ,dr   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,cr   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,amt  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE accounts(
   id   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,name VARCHAR(55)  DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO accounts(id,name) VALUES (1,'C1');
INSERT INTO accounts(id,name) VALUES (2,'C2');
INSERT INTO accounts(id,name) VALUES (3,'C3');

INSERT INTO transactions(id,date,dr,cr,amt) VALUES (1,'2020-01-01',1,2,100);
INSERT INTO transactions(id,date,dr,cr,amt) VALUES (2,'2020-01-01',1,2,200);
INSERT INTO transactions(id,date,dr,cr,amt) VALUES (3,'2020-01-02',1,3,100);
INSERT INTO transactions(id,date,dr,cr,amt) VALUES (4,'2020-01-03',3,2,100);
```

---

```
SELECT date, dr as id, balance FROM (
  SELECT date, dr, SUM(amt) OVER (PARTITION BY dr ORDER BY date ) as balance FROM transactions
  GROUP BY date, dr, amt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date, cr, -SUM(amt) OVER (PARTITION BY cr ORDER BY date ) as balance FROM transactions
  GROUP BY date, cr, amt
) as balances
GROUP BY date, dr, balance
ORDER BY date, dr, balance
```

**Output**

| date | id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 300 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | -300 |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | 400 |
| 2020-01-02 | 3 | -100 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | -400 |
| 2020-01-03 | 3 | 100 |

---

Trying to arrive at the output as shown below, taking into consideration of debit and credit accounts. But as you can see, the balance of `C3` on `2020-01-03` is `100` instead of `0`. What am I doing wrong?

| id | name | date | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 2020-01-01 | 300 |
| 2 | C2 | 2020-01-01 | -300 |
| 1 | C1 | 2020-01-02 | 400 |
| 3 | C3 | 2020-01-02 | -100 |
| 2 | C2 | 2020-01-03 | -400 |
| 3 | C3 | 2020-01-03 | 000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wvLnmAJJSCw92VFAaLT7VP/2)

Comment: This is expected behaviour you need a group by rather than sum()..over

Comment: Where that -300 comes from?

Comment: well, that was the output i am trying to achieve. Question updated with more clarity.

Comment: The result you show is not a running balance. It's just the end balance.

Comment: i have added more transactions and the date column to show the running balance.

Answer (score 3):

Union the dr's and crs

```
SELECT 
  acc.id, 
  acc.name, 
  SUM(tx.amt) as balance 
FROM 
  accounts acc 
  JOIN transactions tx ON tx.dr = acc.id
GROUP BY   acc.id,   acc.name
UNION  ALL
SELECT 
  acc.id, 
  acc.name, 
  SUM(tx.amt * -1) as balance 
FROM 
  accounts acc 
  JOIN transactions tx ON tx.CR = acc.id
GROUP BY   acc.id,   acc.name;
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost did it. But I think I need to find debits and credits separately and subtract credits from debits for each account.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution, though very convoluted! Any other optimized solutions ?

```
WITH debits AS (
    SELECT d1.dr as id, d1.date, coalesce(d1.debit, 0) as debit FROM (
        SELECT dr, date,
            amt as debit
        FROM transactions
        GROUP BY dr, date, amt
    ) as d1
    GROUP BY d1.dr, d1.date, d1.debit
),
credits as (
    SELECT c1.cr as id, c1.date, coalesce(c1.credit, 0) as credit FROM (
        SELECT cr, date,
            amt as credit
        FROM transactions
        GROUP BY cr, date, amt
    ) as c1
    GROUP BY c1.cr, c1.date, c1.credit
),
ledger as (
    SELECT id, date, debit, 0 AS credit FROM debits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, date, 0 AS debit, credit FROM credits
    ORDER BY date, id
)
SELECT id, date,
       sum( coalesce(SUM(debit), 0) - coalesce(SUM(credit), 0) ) over (partition by id order by date) as balance
FROM ledger
GROUP BY date, id
ORDER by date, id, balance
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wvLnmAJJSCw92VFAaLT7VP/3)